lit-html not updating radio button
I have that Quiz Editor - https://quiz-land.github.io/edit/XSZ5weNxLN.
Link to the specific part of the code where the problems occur - https://github.com/.../main/src/views/editor.js/answers.js.
When I added a new question /+ Add question/, it shows a new question form with 2 empty answers. When I marked the second answer /click on the second radio button/, then I deleted the first answer /click on the first trash can/, the second answer becomes first and the marked radio button is saved. So far so good.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
BUT when I added a new answer /+ Add answer/, I marked the second answer /click on the second radio button/, then I deleted the first answer /click on the first trash can/, the second answer becomes first but this time the marked radio button ISN'T saved /the radio button becomes UNchecked/.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Does anyone have any idea why that anomaly occurs and how could I solve the problem?
Thanks in advances for given time!
Greetings,
Johanna Konova.

Please provide a minimal reproductible example that helps us understand your problem.

I'm so sorry, I thought I had already added link to code. I've just edited the post and added a link to the specific part of the code where the problems occur. Here is the whole repository of the app - https://github.com/quiz-land/quiz-land.github.io

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are likely rendering a list of items without an explicit binding for the checked state.
If you wish to preserve the checked state in the DOM, you want to make sure the DOM node is tied to the particular list item, for which you can use the repeat directive. See more here: https://lit.dev/docs/templates/lists/#the-repeat-directive
You would need to make sure each list item, "answers" in your case, have a uniquely identifiable key.
